# Conceptual Question: What would happen to satellites orbiting the earth if mass of earth suddenly increases?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity, centripetal-force

Would the satellite crash onto the earth? If so, why, and in what kind of motion? A spiral motion sounds intuitive, but why?

Or there is another possibility: will the satellite continue to execute circular (I'm aware it is elliptical, but assume it's circular for the sake of simplicity) motion about the earth? But even for this, there's 4 possibilities (by $M =\omega^2 R^3 / G$ when you equate $F_c = F_g$):

1. Circular motion at larger distance away from earth, but at the same angular velocity.
2. Circular motion at same distance from earth, but at higher angular velocity.
3. Circular motion at smaller distance from earth, but higher angular velocity (such that increase in $\omega^2$ outweighs increase in $R^3$).
4. Circular motion at larger distance from earth, but at smaller angular velocity (such that increase in $R^3$ outweighs increase in $\omega^2$).

I'm aware this is a very theoretical (and one based on a highly unrealistic scenario) question, but I feel this has the power to clarify some of my underlying misconceptions about circular motion.

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: I expect that your question was closed as non-mainstream because you can't instantly increase the Earth's mass without defying the laws of physics. So you need to address that, somehow.

Comment: I think adjusting the mass of the central object is (although unlikely) a physically interesting phenomenon which occurs during mass accretion (think black hole growth) or mass loss (think supernova or galactic winds). So Earth-specific may not be very realistic but this touches on some interesting general physical principles IMO.

Comment: This answer from our sister site https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/19802/16685 discusses the change on Earth's orbit as the Sun loses mass (due to radiation and solar wind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an initial circular orbit, force balance shows that:

$\frac{v^{2}}{r} = \frac{GM}{r^{2}}$

You basically ask, what if

$\frac{v^{2}}{r} < \frac{GM}{r^{2}}$ for a particle with distance $r$ from the center of the Earth of mass M and tangential velocity $v$.

This is a similar qualitative description as if the velocity suddenly slowed. The object would be on a new elliptical path. Its current location would be the apoapse (and obviously the periapse would be lower, on the opposite side). If the Earth's mass suddenly increased enough, so that the periapse is lower than the Earth's radius, or crosses the atmosphere, then the satellite crashes into the Earth. But while it is in space, its path is elliptical.

Although the angular momentum has not changed, the angular velocity will be the same for an instant while it stays at its previous radius... but then $L = mr^{2}\omega$ so the angular velocity will increase as the distance to the center of the Earth decreases.